# How to make the author's name appear in my citations

Tags: citing

Can someone please help me out of this problem?
My references now suddenly appear as (21) instead of the usual (Ferrero, 1997). I don't know what I did wrong. I would really appreciate a quick response. Thank you

Comment: You have probably changed your citing style from author-year to numeric. What do you use to handle your bibliography? `biblatex`? `natbib+bibtex`? A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) could help.

Answer (score 3):

Using the package natbib you would get the references by the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum} %just to get some text
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] \citep{Ferrero:1997} \lipsum[2] \citet{Doe:1999}.

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[Ferrero, 1997]{Ferrero:1997}
Fererro, X.Y., 1997. text of the rest of the reference.

\bibitem[Doe, 1999]{Doe:1999}
Doe, J., 1999. another reference

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

The key in this case is in the \bibitem format. So depending on your own setup this can be used as a template for your referencing. An MWE of your document as suggested by Corentin would be useful to provide more details. Note that I used both the passive `\citep` and active `\citet` ways to reference in the text in the example.